# Is there a way to get referral or UTM codes when chrome extension is installed?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

We are developing a Chrome WebStore extension but we do not how to track source (http referrer, utm codes, etc.) when the extension is installed by a user.

In other words, we would like to to get referrer and/or UTM codes of the webstore page when our chrome extension is installed. Is that possible?

For example,

1. user lands on extension page which has the following URL:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/expedia/cfbpcgmafclgfmpoelldpmiolgblgbel?utm_source=test

2. user install the extensions
3. we would like to know what is utm_source.

Comment: look at inline install instead. source will show in analytics

Comment: @ZigMandel Thanks for suggestion - we do have inline install. However that is not what we are looking for: The problem is that there are web pages, posts, etc. which point to our chrome extension webstore and we would like to track performance of them. I.e., do we need to change description on our webstore, do we need to make better tiles, etc.

Comment: As of 06/12/2018, inline installation is deprecated by Google

Comment: Any updates on how this is done?